# Show popup only once (magnific popup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, popup

Trying to show this popup only once per visit. I feel like I'm missing something

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js">
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
var check_cookie = $.cookie('bsw');
   if(check_cookie == null){
    $.cookie('bsw', 'yes', {expires: 1 });
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
});
</script>

<script>
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        // retrieved this line of code from http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: '/bsw-10-off.png'
            },
            type: 'image'

          // You may add options here, they're exactly the same as for $.fn.magnificPopup call
          // Note that some settings that rely on click event (like disableOn or midClick) will not work here
        }, 0);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Am I not closing or opening something right? I feel like the issue is within the document ready function but I could be wrong. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Below is the code with no cookie code

```
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type:'image'});
});
</script>

<script>
(function($) {
    $(window).load(function () {
        // retrieved this line of code from http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api
        $.magnificPopup.open({
            items: {
                src: 'http://www.barbershopwindow.com/bfimages/bsw-10-off.png'
            },
            type: 'image'

          // You may add options here, they're exactly the same as for $.fn.magnificPopup call
          // Note that some settings that rely on click event (like disableOn or midClick) will not work here
        }, 0);
    });
})(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: You never mentioned what isn't working.

Comment: First of all, you have a missing close curly brace on the `if` in your cookie code.

Comment: Issue is it keeps appearing

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

> // retrieved this line of code from http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#api

you may simply trigger click event after initializing your magnificPopup.

Moreover, ***$.cookie('bsw')***  returns undefined and not null if the cookie does not exist.

Working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ywoyvt3/).

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var check_cookie = $.cookie('bsw');
    if (check_cookie == undefined) {
        $.cookie('bsw', 'yes', {expires: 1});
        $('.image-link').magnificPopup({type: 'image'}).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/magnific-popup.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/magnific-popup.js/1.1.0/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.js"></script>



<a class="image-link" href="http://farm4.staticflickr.com/3721/9207329484_ba28755ec4_o.jpg">Open popup</a>
```

Comment: Worked on fiddle but im not getting a ready is not a function error on my site on console

Comment: Looks like that jquery interferes with other elements on the page

Comment: Updated code to include which Jquery version the page is utilizing. Looks like I need to use that full code for it to work. Right now the popup shows no problem but the cookie function does not

Comment: @MHeredia Did you respect the order and version of libraries? See the snippet or the fiddle